# "He could get a new job if he really tried."

Tags: conditional-constructions

> He could get a new job if he really tried.

It's the second condition of if clause but why we used "could"?

I know that *could* is the simple past form of *can* so in this case we have 2 past simple and the rule for the second condition of if clause is that we should put past simple in if clause sentence and present simple in the other sentence. For example: "If he came we would win the game."

So in the first sentence why we put "could"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't so different if you reverse the sentence

> He **could** get a new job if he really tried.

to

> If he really tried he **could** get a new job.

which has a similar construction to your second example

> If he came we **would** win the game.

That leaves the use of **could** or **would**.

Applying for a job, or playing a game, do not have a definite result, but the different phrasing shows the level of *optimism*, *belief*, *likelihood* or even *certainty*.

When applying for a job, the competition is unknown, so **could** is the right condition, especially as you are not usually in direct competition with the other applicants (unless it is a TV show).

In the case of playing a game, the facts about the teams and the players are known, and if a good player turns up, that can make the output more likely and gives a psychological advantage too. This is why you say

> If he came we **would** win the game.

To promote a bigger psychological advantage for winning the game, I suggest the stronger

> If he comes we **will** win the game.